# firebase hosting não entende meu dominio escolar.sjc.br

Tags: firebase, domínio

Recentemente surgiu uma nova categoria de dominio no Brasil o sjc.br então fui e comprei escolar.sjc.br

mas quando tento vincular este meu dominio ao firebase hosting ele apenas entende como sjc.br

minha duvida é se esta nova categoria precisa ser adicionada no firebase? caso sim com fazer isso

caso não seja possível adicionar o firebase hosting infelizmente vou ter que abandonar o serviço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrando em contato com a Google me responderem que o sufixo .sjc.br não se encontra na lista  https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat que eles usam como base

Comment: Tenho um domínio .campinas.br que pode ser inserido. Entretanto, não consigo confirmar o endereço (após inserir no Registro BR). A tela de confirmação entende que sou o proprietário do domínio campinas.br

Comment: Comigo aconteceu a mesma coisa, pelo jeito não resolveram ainda.. resolve hospedar no github mesmo

Comment: vc colocou no github e definiu o dominio? tá usando o firebase pra outras coisas ainda? tem como vc compartilhar o link aqui?

Comment: Então utilizei o gitihub apenas para hospedar o site, e continuei usando o Firebase database, e sim ficou meu domínio .SJC.br para isto necessário uma configuração como estou no seu celular não tenho fácil mas só pesquisar no Google que acha facil

Comment: bacana!! mas o link a que eu me referi é o link do seu app :)

Answer (score 0):

Já faz um tempo essa pergunta mas encontrei uma outra solução que pode ajudar nesse sentido.

Entrando em contato com o suporte do Firebase, me foi enviada uma URL que permite verificar subdomínios de forma mais assertiva do que pela interface do Firebase.

A URL é https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification-success?hl=pt-BR&domain=[seu_subdominio]

Ao entrar nessa URL, você será conduzido para colocar um código TXT no seu provedor de DNS, o que é parecido com o que é feito no Firebase. Entretanto, essa verificação funciona e faz com que esse subdomínio seja reconhecido como seu em toda a plataforma Google (ao que parece).

Após isso, basta ir no Firebase, recarregar a página e solicitar novamente a inclusão do domínio. Ao inserir o endereço, o Firebase já reconhecerá que o domínio é seu e fornecerá os endereços para inclusão no DNS.